# What RhoResolution means exactly in the MATLAB Hough transform function?

Tags: matlab, hough-transform

I'm trying to understand the Hough Transform function in MATLAB. What RhoResolution means exactly in the function?

Answer (score 1):

Rho and theta resolution are essentially the step size for rho and theta voting bins.

The accumulator is a rho(y), theta(x) matrix of 'bins'. Each angle of theta at the distance from the origin (rho) fills the appropriate bin (theta-x, rho-y) with a vote for every white pixel in an edge image (like canny produces).

So by changing the 'resolution' you're really changing the focus of x and y on the accumulator. Kind of like filtering the accumulator so that more votes fill the bins.

The link has a good explanation... also another page at that site that cleared a lot up for me

http://matlabtricks.com/post-41/understanding-the-hough-transform-2